# File.Open doesn't throw IOException when File.Move does

Tags: c#, ioexception

I face weird problem with `IOException` on different servers. Here is my story:

I have win server (C#) that monitors folder for file changes. Also, a FTP server (WinSSHD) is pointed on same folder. When someone uploads a file WinService checks is write complete or not. If file is uploaded WinService renames it via File.Move method.

Is write complete check is made by File.Open method. Like this:

```
public static bool IsWriteComplete(string filePath)
{
    bool isWriteComplete;
    FileStream stream = null;
    try
    {
        stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite|FileShare.Delete);
        isWriteComplete = true;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        isWriteComplete = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isWriteComplete = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null) { stream.Close(); }
    }
    return isWriteComplete;
}
```

For some reason on one server it works perfectly (Win2003SP2) and on another one (Win2003SP1) is not working at all. The `IsWriteComplete` method says True, WinServer tries to move file and dies by `IOException` later. I haven't found any references regarding such issue.

To fix the issue I replaced `File.Open` by `File.Move`.
Before:

```
stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite|FileShare.Delete);
```

After:

```
File.Move(filePath, filePath);
```

And now it works on second server (Win2003SP1) and doesn't work on first one (Win2003SP2).

Does anybody know why it works as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause of the behavior.
There was different FTP service installed: Techia. For some reason Tectia doesn't set write lock on uploading files. That's why File.Open(filePath, FileAccess.Write) doesn't throw IOException.

Answer (score 4):

When you use File.Open you have a "race condition", even if you use FileShare.None - after you close the file, another thread/process can sneak in and lock the file (open it) before you call File.Move. This other process might not be the FTP server, but could be something you are not even aware of, such as a virus checker. Thus you should use File.Move instead of File.Open, and catch the IOException if the File.Move fails, and then retry, until it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `FileShare.ReadWrite|FileShare.Delete`, you allow other processes to read, write or delete the file while you're opening it. On the other side, you can open the file while others also access it. So, try `FileShare.None` to open the file exclusively, which should fail as long as the file is in use by the FTP server.

Also, you should use `FileAccess.ReadWrite` to make sure that you have full access to the file. You do not know how the FTP server locks the file, maybe it allows other processes to open the file in read-mode and declines write mode while the upload is still in process. So, `FileAccess.ReadWrite` is better.

MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileaccess.aspx

About your code:

```
catch (IOException)
{
    isWriteComplete = false;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    isWriteComplete = false;
}
```

The catch block for `IOException` is not neccessary if you also catch `Exception`...

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'll check that. Catch statement is duplicated because of additional logging that I just removed from code sample.

Comment: The purpose of the FileShare.ReadWrite|FileShare.Delete is to prevent file be locked by IsWriteComplete method. The method shouldn't do any locks, cause checks for locks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can check in other way then open method.

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
bool isNormal = ((fileInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.Normal) == FileAttributes.Normal);

//or 

bool isReadOnly = ((fileInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

You can find the method in either way in order to understand whether file is available or not. And you can continue based upon the status.

Please let me know if you are looking for some other things.

Comment: I just tried to check with FileIOPermissions like
var fileIoPerm = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, filePath);
fileIoPerm.Demand();
It's not working. Security exception is not thrown even I know that file is still uploading.

Comment: which operation actually performs uploading? If its source code is yours then you may need to set file attributes to normal. Then, once upload completed then you need to attribute as readonly. We are just using this attribute as a flag.

Comment: Uploading is performed by FTP Server.